# I can't find any downloadable apps on Ubuntu Software(app store)

Tags: 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, can't really find any downloadable apps. All I see is installed apps. 
It's my first time with ubuntu so short solutions will seem much better.

Comment: Run Updates before anything else. Install the updates, reboot and try again.

Comment: How long ago was the install? Did you run `sudo apt update` after installing? If not ... do so ;-)

Comment: did it multiple times, i can see all applications in the the software installed one app,comix, which would not open after opening once and now it won't uninstall. can't download vlc, it is stuck on installing. Other apps which i chose to update are stuck too.

Comment: now vlc says waiting to install on the launcher but it says install in the software manager. also I cannot uninstall comix, i click remove but after some time it gets just the same. Also can't open it too.